# Laravel - Subdomain route prefixes causes other routes to not return "Not found"

Tags: php, laravel, routes

[NOTE] - This issue was found to be due to incorrect Apache configuration. I have posted an answer which explains what I did wrong. I hope this helps!

---

I'm starting a project with Laravel and I've begun with creating the general routes. I want to create a request structure so that URLs of `example.com` go to organic routes, `admin.example.com` go to the admin dashboard of my app, and `{workspace}.example.com` goes to a dynamic route for my users' personal workspaces.

Currently I have the following routing structure:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.example.com'), function() {

    Route::get('/', function() {
        echo 'This route works fine';
    });

    Route::get('/test', function() {
        // This route doesn't work...
        echo 'Test';
    });

});


Route::group(array('domain' => '{workspace}.example.com'), function() {

    Route::get('/', function() {
        echo 'This route works fine';
    });

    Route::get('/test', function() {
        // This route doesn't work...
        echo 'Test';
    });

});


Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.com'), function() {

    Route::get('/', function() {
        echo 'This route works fine';
    });

    Route::get('/test', function() {
        // This route doesn't work...
        echo 'Test';
    });

});
```

As you see, I have three routing groups. The first is for the admin prefixed URLs (to ensure that `admin.example.com` is not mistaken for a workspace prefix). There is the workspace prefix, and then finally the no-prefix route group.

As indicated in the code, all `Route::get('/', ...` routes work fine, however anything that is not the root does not work. I am receiving 404 errors when trying to go to `example.com/test` (and all the other domain prefixes).

What can I do to my routing to fix this and get the routes `Route::get('/test', ...` to work rather than just the `/` routes?

Much appreciated!

Comment: If you get rid of all your route groups and just have simple, group-less `Route::get('/')` and `Route::get('/test')`, does the `/test` route work? I have a sneaking suspicion this has nothing to do with groups/subdomains and everything to do with your webserver/`.htaccess` config.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Thank you for your response! I have just tested this and it turns out that it doesn't work! I had used basic routes before and it worked just fine. Obviously some config has been changed which is causing the issue. Any ideas of what could do this? Thanks

Comment: @ceejayoz - I'm just being stupid! I changed my DocumentRoot to the Laravel project and in turn didn't set `AllowOverride` to `All` in the apache conf. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: That'll do it! Glad I could help you get to the cause. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being caused by the Apache configuration being incorrect rather than the routing being incorrect.

To avoid having issues like this in future, ensure that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in your project's `<Directory /var/www/myProject/public>` block the apache.conf file like below:

```
<Directory /var/www/myProject/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```